# git revision number and commit details in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have to fill one component.properties file with the source commit id and commit message from git.

How can I do it with maven? Should I add something to the  pom.xml?

Comment: hi. what do you want to perform exactly in maven ? what is your goal?

Comment: it's not clear what you want

Comment: During the maven build, I have to add the commit details what is the source of the build to the specified file.
This file would be very good for my testers to know which commit was the source of the tested binary.

Comment: Did you already look at this: https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin?

Comment: It helps thank you

Comment: The plugin is working very fine but can I add an extra row to the generated file? I would add the Jenkins build number what is in local environment variable.